# Create element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I wrote this sctipt that creates an Line Chart on an **existing** canvas:

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
```

And on animation Complete it opens the generated **Line Chart-Canvas** in a new tab:

```
 var options =  { onAnimationComplete: function(){
                    window.open(canvas.toDataURL());
                }}
```

Here you can test it out: https://jsfiddle.net/ds53js5u/3/

**What I try to achieve:**

Is to also **generate the canvas with Jquery**

I replaced:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

With:

```
var canvas = $('<canvas/>', {id: "myChart", width: 400, height: 400});
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/ds53js5u/4/

But now **It doesn't any more generate the DataUrl** and open it in the new window! What do i wrong?

**It is important for me that the canvas is never drawn to the document!**

THANKS

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hqq4sv9h/1/

Comment: P.S, why waiting for an animation to complete since you don't want it visible? add `animation: false,` to your `options`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your element creation syntax. But you are trying to execute a DOM method on a jQuery object. use:

```
canvas[0].toDataURL(); // => "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAACWCAYAAABkW7XSAAAEYklEQ…mqBCVAwGD5AQIEMgIGK1OVoAQIGCw/QIBARsBgZaoSlACBB1YxAJfjJb2jAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
```

Comment: You need to append the element which you have created to the html page still:


`var canvas = $('<canvas/>', {id: "myChart", width: 400, height: 400});`


`$('body').append(canvas);`


`console.log(canvas[0].toDataURL());`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this script:

```
var canvas = $('<canvas/>', {id: "myChart", width: 400, height: 400});

var ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");


var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        }
    ]
};

var options =  {onAnimationComplete: function(){
                window.open(canvas[0].toDataURL());}}

var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
```

Comment: Sorry but seems like it does nothing: jsfiddle.net/ds53js5u/8

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling native [HTTPCanvasElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement) methods on jQuery object, which of course fails. You need to fix 2 problems.

1. Append canvas to body in order to use it. For example, by using [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) method.
2. Use HTMLElement as `canvas` variable instead of jQuery collection instance. You can get HTMLElement object from jQuery collection as the first element of this collection (`[0]`).

Fixed code would be:

```
var canvas = $('<canvas/>', {id: "myChart", width: 400, height: 400}).appendTo('body')[0]
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/ds53js5u/5/

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack around to ensure the canvas is never drawn to the element but is displayed on the popup - but it works, and is generating with javascript, not jQuery.

https://jsfiddle.net/btzqqq9v/

HTML

```
<div id="canvasContainer" style="position:absolute; visibility:hidden"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var s = '<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>';
var div = document.getElementById('canvasContainer');
div.innerHTML = s;
var canvas = div.firstChild;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```